# Grid with images (height: 100%; width: 100%;) comes out behind content of parent block

Tags: html, css, image, grid-layout

Code:

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.images_grid {
  height: 500px;
}

.images_grid__content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas: "image_1 image_3 image_5 image_6" "image_2 image_4 image_5 image_7";
}

.images_grid__image {
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: bottom;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.images_grid__image_1 {
  grid-area: image_1;
}

.images_grid__image_2 {
  grid-area: image_2;
}

.images_grid__image_3 {
  grid-area: image_3;
}

.images_grid__image_4 {
  grid-area: image_4;
}

.images_grid__image_5 {
  grid-area: image_5;
}

.images_grid__image_6 {
  grid-area: image_6;
}

.images_grid__image_7 {
  grid-area: image_7;
}
```

```html
<div class="images_grid">
  <div class="images_grid__content">
    <img class="images_grid__image_1 images_grid__image" alt="Image 1" src="image.png">
    <img class="images_grid__image_2 images_grid__image" alt="Image 2" src="image.png">
    <img class="images_grid__image_3 images_grid__image" alt="Image 3" src="image.png">
    <img class="images_grid__image_4 images_grid__image" alt="Image 4" src="image.png">
    <img class="images_grid__image_5 images_grid__image" alt="Image 5" src="image.png">
    <img class="images_grid__image_6 images_grid__image" alt="Image 6" src="image.png">
    <img class="images_grid__image_7 images_grid__image" alt="Image 7" src="image.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Description:

The grid with images (auto×736.233) comes out behind content of the parent block (auto×500)

Tutorial:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-an-image-gallery-with-css-grid-e0f0fd666a5c/

Preview:

[Preview 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmXsr.png)

[Preview 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymlUO.png)

Image:

[image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3SmW.png) (505px x 758px)

Why does the grid comes out behind the parent block and how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.images_grid__content {
    ...
    height: 100%;  
}
```

height had the value auto and was formed by the content, making it the size of the parent the problem was solved